# How do I force the navbar toggle to the left of Brand in bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following template so far:

```
     <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class='navbar-header'>
                    <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse'>
                        <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class='navbar-brand' href=""><img src="images/Evaluate_Pharma_Logo_220.png" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear-fix"></div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">
                                <input type="text" /><span class="fa fa-search big"> </span> SEARCH
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">
                                <span class=""></span>BROWSE DATA
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                CREATE REPORT
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="" rel="Company & Country Profiles">Company &amp; Country Profiles</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                PEER GROUPS
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                YOUR EVALUATION
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


            </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this I obtain my menu as expected, but when I reduce the width of the page my navbar toggle button class appear to the right of navbar-brand. I need this to be to the left of this, how can I make that happen? This is just the shell, I know I need to fill in my hrefs and other stuff

Comment: Please post the full code, or create a Fiddle

Comment: @Yuri I've edited my question to show the full page as it stands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrap floats it right, so you would override it with:

```
.navbar-toggle {
  float: left !important;
}
```

note: using "!important" is not best practice, so alternatively add a new id selector to the same button element as .navbar-toggle, and add the same property and value.